# MS Graph .NET SDK: Update API OAuth permission scopes fails

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am working in a .NET6 application with the MS Graph SDK

- Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph package, version 2.10.0
- Microsoft.Graph package, version 5.9.0

All actions are working fine, except 1: update the ApiApplication Oauth2Permissionscopes.
Initially, I create an application with 2 scopes. Then, a 3rd one needs to be added, so according to documentation, you should do a PATCH on the Application, with the properties you want to update

```
await _client.Applications[applicationId].PatchAsync(patch)
```

where 'patch' is defined as

```
var patch = new Application
{
    Api = new ApiApplication {
        Oauth2PermissionScopes = permissionScopesToAdd
    }
};
```

'permissionScopesToAdd is just a list with 1 item to be added.
In this case, the exception that is given says that 'Permission (scope or role) cannot be deleted or updated unless disabled first'.
This gave me the idea 'oh, it tries to delete the ones I did not pass', so in a next try, I included the existing ones as well, but then got an error saying 'Id already exists'.

In some articles on support tickets, I see advice on using UpdateAsync(), but this method just is not available in the package mentioned above. Only 'GetAsync', 'DeleteAsync' and 'PatchAsync' are available.

So, I'm a bit stuck here with this, as I don't seem to find any solution for it. In the beginning, I used Powershell, which did work, but used the Mg-UpdateApplication statement instead.

In the documentation, no mention is given on using a different path (which is required when adding owners or adding an application secret).